# How to process buy sell history csv

Tags: python, csv, queue, stock, fifo

I have a csv like this:

```
symbol  date                           side    quantity   average_price
AAPL    2020-12-31T14:28:48.019000Z    buy     1          112.01
AMD     2020-12-29T19:14:21.111000Z    buy     1          91.33
AMD     2020-12-29T14:28:48.019000Z    sell    5          92.42
AAPL    2020-12-28T19:14:21.111000Z    sell    3          115.45
AAPL    2020-12-23T14:28:48.019000Z    buy     1          108.11
AAPL    2020-12-20T19:14:21.111000Z    sell    2          110.03
AMD     2020-12-18T14:28:48.019000Z    buy     7          88.74
AAPL    2020-12-16T19:14:21.111000Z    buy     4          100.93
```

This is just a small sample of the data with only 2 companies AAPL and AMD. The actual csv is much longer than this with many more companies.

Given that I have 1 share of AAPL and 3 shares of AMD. I need to figure out the transaction dates and price that I purchased these shares. So the result I am looking for is:

```
1 share of APPL on 2020-12-31T14:28:48.019000Z for 112.01
```

and

```
1 share of AMD on 2020-12-29T19:14:21.111000Z for 91.33
2 shares of AMD on 2020-12-18T14:28:48.019000Z for 88.74
```

Basically this is calculated on a FIFO basis. AMD: 7-5+1=3 and APPL: 4-2+1-3+1=1...

I really have no idea how to go about this... I was thinking maybe using a queue? somehow? But before going down that path... I thought I should post this and see if there is a better way?

FYI... Current csv is 700 rows... Could be much larger in the future. Maybe 7000 rows? Might be relevant if any solutions involve iterating through the csv.

Answer (score 0):

Look at it in an analytical way, as if YOU were the software, and make (solid) rules for yourself about the process.  It's (relatively) slow to seek reverse line-by-line through a text file, so maybe first import the lines in a structure or sqlite memory database where seeking is fast.

You can make a subquery by company, and order by date. Then you can reverse through that subquery for your "FIFO".

I can't really get the ordering and sorting and how you combine the buy/sell, but this is probably simple for you to do.

Hope this gives you some inspiration.

Comment: A solid rule for myself is that I am using "import robin_stocks as rs" a library for an investment API. This library has "rs.export.export_completed_stock_orders()" as the only  means that I can find to obtain the date of a "buy." This function creates a csv file. It seems as though my only choice is working with this csv file. Which I am not sure how to do. Obviously, I don't want my code to be slow, but slow isn't really a problem in this case. I may run this code once per day at most. Maybe once per week.